# What's the smallest size a cairngorm project can be?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3, cairngorm

That is , what's the size of the bootstrap code for cairngorm framework which is based on flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Cairngorm adds very little size since it's more of a meta-framework than a large collection of classes. Cairngorm 3 uses multiple libraries so the size varies depending on which pieces you use. The Cairngorm 2 SWC is 12KB meaning the smallest size is less than that. The size of the Flex framework also varies and, when considering things like RSLs, is a complicated topic, but it's minimum size is usually about 400KB i think.